# No {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope element was found

Tags: python, soap, wsdl

I am trying to dig deep into SOAP and WSDL concepts. I am using Python's spyne lib, and have successfully implemented the hello world example described in the [doc](http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/manual/02_helloworld.html)
Basically, I have the server.py and client.py files, where

server.py

```
from spyne import Application, rpc, ServiceBase, Iterable, Integer, Unicode

from spyne.protocol.soap import Soap11
from spyne.server.wsgi import WsgiApplication


class HelloWorldService(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(Unicode, Integer, _returns=Iterable(Unicode))
    def say_hello(ctx, name, times):
        ...
    
    
application = Application([HelloWorldService], 'spyne.examples.hello.soap',
                              in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
                              out_protocol=Soap11())
    
    wsgi_application = WsgiApplication(application)
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import logging
    
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    
    server = make_server('127.0.0.1', 8000, wsgi_application)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Now, just for the sake of experiment, I want to send via Postman a request with XML body (instead of using libs like `suds`.

The body that I send via Postman looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tran="spyne.examples.hello.soap">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tran:say_hello>
            <tran:name>ASD</tran:name>
            <tran:times>5</tran:times>
        </tran:say_hello>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now I end up with the following error message:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap11env:Body>
        <soap11env:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap11env:Client.SoapError</faultcode>
            <faultstring>No {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope element was found!</faultstring>
            <faultactor></faultactor>
        </soap11env:Fault>
    </soap11env:Body>
</soap11env:Envelope>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SOAP namespace is wrong. Your message has this namespace:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ...
```

The correct SOAP namespace for a SOAP envelope is the one mentioned in the error message:

```
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
```

Like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ...
```